# Using gherkin with Java. Copy @Given tag value as sting

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, extentreports

I got a gherkin+java tests and ExtentReports to generate reports. I found couple solutions to print out my ExtentReports in gherkin format as well. So, I used https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java for BDD. The problem is that I got code like:

```
 @Given("^I navigates to My Account page$")
    public void I_navigates_to_My_Account_page() throws Throwable {
        com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest given = scenario.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("Given"), "I navigates to My Account page").info("info");
```

But I would like not to copy @Given value and to use it's value and use a variable instead like:

```
@Given("^I navigates to My Account page$")
        public void I_navigates_to_My_Account_page() throws Throwable {
            com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest given = scenario.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("Given"), getGivenText()).info("info");
```

[image: snapshot]

where getGivenText will receive "I navigates to My Account page" value on execution. I tried ti find solution for this, but no success. If anybody had this problem and found solution, please, let me know. Thank you!

Comment: As Given, Then.... annotations are ignored while regex method matching you will an issue with the hardcoding of "given" to the GherkinKeyword constructor. The step in feature file might have a When or Then with the same text but report will show Given.

Comment: Have you looked at existing formatters which output cucumber reports with extent - https://github.com/sitture/cucumber-jvm-extentreport or https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter. The first one is based on Cucumber 2.0